# How do I move the background image to the back and the login container to the front

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to move `antoine-barres.jpg` background image all the way to the back, then the `clouds.png`, then the login container all the way to the front. How do I do it, I have tried z-index but not sure how it works, I have tried but ran out of ideas, please help.

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="page-header" style="background-image: url('../assets/img/antoine-barres.jpg');">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" style="z-index:9999;">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto mr-auto">
                        <div class="card card-register">
                            <h3 class="title">Welcome</h3>
                            <form class="register-form">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-round">Register</button>
                            </form>
                            <div class="forgot">
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-danger">Forgot password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer register-footer text-center">
                    <h6>&copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>, made with <i class="fa fa-heart heart"></i> by Creative Tim</h6>
                </div>
            </div>                
        </div>
    <div class="moving-clouds" style="background-image: url('../assets/img/clouds.png');">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: please provide some reference link

Comment: Basically, I went to this free template site [link](http://demo.themequarry.com/theme/paper-kit-2-free-bootstrap-4-ui-kit-ASFEDAB6) and I saw the background image with moving clouds. Then I went to the register page [link](http://demos.creative-tim.com/paper-kit-2/examples/register.html). I wish to put the background image with the moving clouds at the register page. I hope I can do it, all your help and feedback is gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the moving cloud image before the `container`

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="page-header" style="background-image: url('../assets/img/login-image.jpg');">
        <div class="filter"></div>
        <div class="moving-clouds" style="background-image: url('http://demos.creative-tim.com/paper-kit-2/assets/img/clouds.png');">
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto mr-auto">
                    <div class="card card-register">
                        <h3 class="title">Welcome</h3>
                        <div class="social-line text-center">
                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-neutral btn-facebook btn-just-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-neutral btn-google btn-just-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-neutral btn-twitter btn-just-icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <form class="register-form">
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">

                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-round">Register</button>
                        </form>
                        <div class="forgot">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-danger">Forgot password?</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer register-footer text-center">
                <h6>© <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script><script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>2018, made with <i class="fa fa-heart heart"></i> by Creative Tim</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally works. I have tried so many ways but couldn't get it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @HansheungCheah You're Welcome. Please check the mark on correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.page-header {
    background: url(../assets/img/clouds.png);
}

or

.wrapper {
    background: url(../assets/img/clouds.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understand your problem, can you explain it more?

```css
.wrapper {
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/WP_SOPA_asset_Radial_Gradient.jpg'); // i change url
}

.row {
  z-index: 999;
}

.moving-clouds {
  background: url('http://eskipaper.com/images/simple-cloud-wallpaper-1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 ml-auto mr-auto">
          <div class="card card-register">
            <h3 class="title">Welcome</h3>
            <form class="register-form">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">

              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-round">Register</button>
            </form>
            <div class="forgot">
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-danger">Forgot password?</a>
              <div class="footer register-footer text-center">
                <h6>&copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script>, made with <i class="fa fa-heart heart"></i> by Creative Tim</h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="moving-clouds"></div>

</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4bmef1qj/1/)